# ～に～ある , unusual usage of に？

Tags: grammar, particle-に, anime

From the anime ノーゲーム・ノーライフ

Context: internet rumors and urban legends are being discussed

> あまたの都市伝説の1つ**に**こんな話があるのを聞いたことはあるだろうか

My interpretation:

> あまたの都市伝説の1つ = "one of many urban legends"
>
> こんな話があるのを聞いたことはあるだろうか = "Have you heard of this rumor?"

That's nice and all, but I just can't understand what に is supposed to mean in this sentence.

I did read [Q: 君に話しがある How does this work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14603/%E5%90%9B%E3%81%AB%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-how-does-this-work) , which didn't really help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's like として.

大辞泉 def. 一９:

> 資格を表す。…として。「委員―君を推す」

Jisho def. 6:

> as (i.e. in the role of)​See also として

Try breaking up the sentence this way: [あまたの都市伝説の1つにこんな話がある] のを聞いたことはあるだろうか.